# Throwing thread 1 signal SIGABRT while trying to implement PARSE PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, backend, pfquery

It doesn't matter what I try I cant seem to even get past changing UITableView with the PFQueryTableViewController. I have added code, gone back through code, got rid of code and it all seems to throw the same error pretty much after changing from UITableView 
i get
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:'-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "2-view-3" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

i'm just trying to populate a table from PARSE, basic stuff but i'm just trying to help my younger brother with my limited capabilities. Any help would be much appreciated

here's some code. i've linked to parse in my appdelegate, all that's fine. ive tested that.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface BaliPartyViewController :  PFQueryTableViewController




@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "BaliPartyViewController.h"
#import "PartyDetailViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"


@interface BaliPartyViewController ()

@end

@implementation BaliPartyViewController {

}


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"Recipe";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"name";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    return query;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
    PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"];
    thumbnailImageView.file = thumbnail;
    [thumbnailImageView loadInBackground];

    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    nameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];

    UILabel *prepTimeLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
    prepTimeLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"prepTime"];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showPartyDetail" sender: self];
    }
}

/*- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPartyDetail"]) {
        PartyDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
        if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
            indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            destViewController.partyName = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            destViewController.partyDate = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            destViewController.information = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            destViewController.location = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        } else {
            indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            destViewController.partyName = [parties objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            destViewController.partyDate = [partyTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            destViewController.information = [information objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            destViewController.location = [location objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            destViewController.photo = [detailPicture objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        }
        // Hide bottom tab bar in the detail view
        destViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    }

}*/




@end
```

Comment: What are you using as your class in Interface Builder/Storyboards?

Comment: still UITableView, following the tutorial it has said to change anything, except PFImage